# Is there a way to automatically match build versions between legacy app and UWP package with Desktop Bridge?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a legacy app that I package in UWP using Desktop Bridge. Where do I configure the build version in the UWP to match the legacy app or vice versa for releases?

Comment: If you publish the app to the sore, and the app version depend  on uwp package, it is will not be associated with legacy app. I don't know why you want match build version between legacy app and uwp package.

Comment: The UWP package has a system Tray app which has a version that is displayed. My goal is to ensure the system tray app version match the version from the UWP

Comment: There is a menu item in your system tray app that  display the app's version, and you want make the its version  same as uwp, right?

Comment: That's correct! At the moment, I am manually changing the build version in the menu tray app to match the version on the UWP app.

Comment: Does the following work  ?

Answer (score 0):

> I am manually changing the build version in the menu tray app to match the version on the UWP app.

You could use `Windows.ApplicationModel` namespace to get your uwp app's version.

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel;

public static string GetAppVersion()
{
  Package package = Package.Current;
  PackageId packageId = package.Id;
  PackageVersion version = packageId.Version;

  return string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build, version.Revision);
}
```

For more info you could refer this blog **[Establishing the Connection](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/)**